# How can I send json formatted data from a client program to a service orchestrator program in a rest call (GET, POST, PUT etc) using a tomcat server?

Tags: java, json, rest, tomcat

I have worked out how to get data from an API using a REST GET call, but I need my program to be able to send data (not from an API) from the client program to the service orchestrator program. I am writing in java, using netbeans 18 and tomcat 9.

I've tried posting the json string like this to the server but I have no idea whether this is working or how to retrieve it from the server when it's been posted.

```
private void addObject(String json) throws MalformedURLException, IOException{
        String body = json;
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/RESTService02/webresources/trip");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

        try (DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream())) {
            dos.writeBytes(body);
            System.out.println("dos = " + dos);
        }

        try (BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = bf.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }                
    }
```

Comment: Please put any errors/responses if you are getting any. And can you see any logs on server?